# Find max N people with 2022 different colored balls choosing two balls each so that no 3 people exactly contain balls of 3 colours

Tags: combinatorics, discrete-mathematics, contest-math, combinations, recreational-mathematics

Here is the "exact" wording given in the problem.

> There are $N$ people. Each person gets two balls of different colours among $2022$ balls with different colours. The combinations of the ball colours they get are different from each other. Find the maximum possible value of $N$ such that no $3$ people exactly contain balls of $3$ colours.

The English sounds a little strange to me as I am still questioning whether I understood the problem correctly. The given "Answer key" (no solution) states $1022121$.

The only number coincidence I can see is that $(2022)(2022)/4 = (1011)^2 = (1011)(1011) = 1022121$ which could mean nothing.

Here are some thoughts regarding how or why I got stuck:

1. Number of ways two get two balls of different colours among $2022$ balls with different colours is $(2022)(2021)/2 = 2043231$.
2. If we choose three colours say $a, b, c$ then the pairs containing those colours are $(a, b), (b,c)$ or $(c, a)$ where order is not important, i.e. there are "three" of them.
3. Number of different three colour combinations which can be derived from $2022$ different colours is $C(2022, 3) = 1 375, 775, 540$.
4. Help part

How do I link these to count the answer of $1022121$?
Am I missing something or did I misunderstand the question?
I have relatively average level secondary school level Math Olympiad abilities.

Any help is appreciated. Thank you.

Jon

Comment: The question is poorly worded, but they mean that there are 2022 colours, and a large supply of balls of those colours. The N people each get two differently coloured balls. There are no three people with the colour pairings (a,b), (b,c), and (a,c) for any three colours a,b,c. What is the largest possible N under these conditions? A good way to hand out the coloured balls is to split the colours into two sets of 1011, and hand every person one of each set. This obviously avoids such triplets. Now you just need to prove this is optimal.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We consider the set $A= \left \{ 1, 2, ..., 2022 \right \}$ and  $2$ subset $A_1, A_2$. We consider the ordered pair $(x,y)$ wher $x \in A_1, y \in A_2$. We call $A_1, A_2$ *good* if there aren't $3$ pair of the form $(a,b),(b,c),(a,c)$ created as explained above. We will prove that if $A_1, A_2$ are *good* then $k \in A_1 \Leftrightarrow k\notin  A_2$. If it is true, then $max(|A_1|+|A_2|)=2022$. Now suppose by contradiction that $g\in A_1,A_2$, and they are *good* so we take $a_1 \in A_1, a_2 \in A_2$, the we can meke the order pairs $(a_1,g),(g,a_2),(a_1,a_2)$, so the contradiction. So we have proved that $k \in A_1 \Leftrightarrow k\notin  A_2$. The number of ordere pairs is $|A_1|×|A_2|$. So for maximize this product with costant sum $2022$, we take $|A_1|=1011,|A_2|=1011$. We can see that it work, so we are done.
Sorry for my bad english.

Comment: If there are maximum $1011^2$  pairs then there are maximum $1011^2$ people because a person matches a pair. I forget to say it in my solution

Comment: Hi there  THANK YOU so much; your explanation has been great. I understand and appreciate it. I know which part I missed namely the split into two subsets to form a pair and how the rule applies and the subsequent optimization for the product (which counts no. of pairs hence number of people N too) which just depends on a two variable AM-GM since sum is fixed meaning it happens in the equality case!

Comment: You are welcome, I'm happy to have been of help :)